# create a new odt-file with python

Tags: python, xml

I have a folder "myfolder" which was created when I had unzipt an odt-file. I had delete the content.xml in the folder. Now I want to add a file called "content.xml" with data in it (here in the variable "content" is the xml-styled text). I tried this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('myfolder', mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        zf.writestr('content.xml', content)
```

I get an odt-file but it is damaged. when I unzip it there is only the content.xml in it. the mode parameter is 'a' so I thougt it will append the content.xml to the other files.

Can anybody help?

Comment: 'Do you think there is a better way to do that?' By what meaning of 'better'? Does your code work?

Comment: That is teh way to do it, if already have teh valid XML content in your variable.

However, getting to this point may be tricky, and that is where third party modules such as PyODF bellow can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the package odfpy.

you can see some info [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odfpy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439396/create-openoffice-odt-document-with-python)

> Odfpy is a library to read and write OpenDocument v. 1.2 files. The
>   main focus has been to prevent the programmer from creating invalid
>   documents. It has checks that raise an exception if the programmer
>   adds an invalid element, adds an attribute unknown to the grammar,
>   forgets to add a required attribute or adds text to an element that
>   doesn’t allow it. It's on pipy, so you can install it with

you can install it with pip:

```
pip install odfpy
```